# Capillary forces in horizontal plane

Tags: physical-chemistry, surface-chemistry, capillary-forces

In a physical chemistry course, we went to the lab and made a microstamp out of an elastomer. This stamp has gaps of 25 µm in width. When the elastomer had hardened, we placed it on a microscope slide and dropped a single drop of epoxy glue to one side of the stamp. Due to capillary forces, the glue migrated slowly to the other side of the stamp.

In my script, there is an equation to calculate the rising height of a liquid due to capillary forces. Our goal is to calculate the surface tension of the glue, knowing the migration speed, the density and the contact angle.

As our stamp is in the horizontal plane, there is no rising height, so how do I manipulate the formula to calculate the surface tension of the epoxy glue in the horizontal plane?

Here is the formula of my script:

$$
h = \frac{2 \sigma \cos \theta}{\rho g r}
$$

Where $\sigma$ is the surface tension, $\theta$ the contact angle, $\rho$ the density of the liquid, $g$ the gravitational acceleration and $r$ the radius of the gap.

And a little picture of our experiment. The glue migrates from the right to the left.

[image]